# How to call Vimeo Api in java

Tags: java, android, oauth-2.0, scribe, vimeo-api

Hye Please help me?i want to call vimeo video search api.when i call search Api through oauth then error comes the oauth signature passed was not valid.this is my code

```
OAuthService service = new ServiceBuilder()
                .provider(VimeoApi.class)
                .apiKey(ApiKey)
                .apiSecret(SecretKey)
                .build();
        OAuthRequest req = new OAuthRequest(Verb.GET, "http://vimeo.com/api/rest/v2?format=json&method=vimeo.videos.search&query=fun");
        Token token = new Token("", "");
        service.signRequest(token, req);

        final Response res = req.send();

        Log.e("vimeo", res.getBody());
```

and this is my error

> {"generated_in":"0.0117","stat":"fail","err":{"code":"401","expl":"The
>   oauth_signature passed was not valid.","msg":"Invalid signature"}}

can anyone tell me what i m doing wrong.if this is not correct way to call vimeo api then can anyone give me small code to access public videos.please help me?i think i am doing some mistake?how can i call  like this api https://api.vimeo.com/videos?page=1&per_page=10&query=naat i dont know the proper method how can i call this api through Oauth.this Question is spexialy ask @prablo.bcz i have visited all question in stackoverflow about vimeo api.
all answer given by u.so please i m waiting of your answer.

Answer (score 0):

The url you are using is an old, deprecated API. The new API uses oauth1, and you can find the documentation here: https://developer.vimeo.com/api